# How to make a dynamic bootstrap pagination with JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, bootstrap-4

So basically I call on this 840 Json Object dataset with AJAX and display it using divs and a simple enough bootstrap pagination. Now my issue is, that I have 94 pages and all the page buttons are getting displayed all the time. I think that is neither practical, pretty or user-friendly so I'd like to fix that.

So I've scoured the internet about this issue. I've found several pagination plugins supposed to deliver exactly what I need like simplePagination.js or twbsPagination. The latter worked the best for me but still didn't function correctly. I was able to get the new pagination up and running but it would not change the actual page content. I have now tried many more plugins and tried modifying my existing code but nothing worked. I reverted my code back to the normal pagination now.

```
pageSize = 9;

    var pageCount = $(".line-content").length / pageSize 
//calculating the number of pages needed
    var pagin = document.getElementById('pagin');
//deleting the previous displayed page buttons
    while (pagin.firstChild) {
        pagin.removeChild(pagin.firstChild);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) { 
//creating the page items
        $("#pagin").append('<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">' + (i + 1) + '</a></li> ');
    }
//styling the current page item
    $("#pagin li").first().find("a").addClass("current") 

    // the function to actually change the content on the selected page
    showPage = function (page) {
        $(".line-content").hide();
        $(".line-content").each(function (n) {
            if (n >= pageSize * (page - 1) && n < pageSize * page)
                $(this).show();
        });
    }

    showPage(1); //displaying the content

    //changing the style
    $("#pagin li a").click(function () {
        $("#pagin li a").removeClass("current");
        $(this).addClass("current");
        showPage(parseInt($(this).text()))
    });
```

So basically I got this working pagination but I'd like to get it sleeker. I'm open to any jquery plugins and everything. As long as it does what I hope it can.
[My pagination looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBU5f.png)
[I'd like to have it looking somewhat like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDw7o.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use **bootpag**,

It's very simple and works good with bootstrap, it also has good documentation to show you how to use it step by step.
I don't have to explain it here since everything is explained on the website.

I hope this can help you.

Link: http://botmonster.com/jquery-bootpag/#pro-page-8

Answer (score 3):

Html

```
<table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Salary</th>
                <th scope="col">Age</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="page-data">


        </tbody>
    </table>
    <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
        <ul class="pagination">
            <li onclick="prePage()" class="page-item page-list">
                <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Previous">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
            </li>

            <li onclick="nextPage()" class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Next">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

JS Code

```
<script>
        let userData = null;
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees",
            type: "get",
            async: false,
            success: function(users) {
                userData = users.data;
            }
        });
        var currentPage = 0;
        let pages = "";
        let page_size = 5;
        pages = paginate(userData, page_size);
        pageLi = "";
        pages.forEach((element, index) => {
            if (index != 0)
                pageLi += '<li onclick="pageChange(' + index + ')" id="page_' + index + '" class="page-item list-item" id="page_' + index + '"><a class="page-link" href="javascript:void(0)">' + index + '</a></li>';
        });
        $(".page-list").after(pageLi);
        page = pages[currentPage];
        printRows(page);

        function nextPage() {
            if (pages.length - 1 > currentPage)
                page = currentPage + 1;
            pageChange(page);
        }

        function prePage() {
            if (currentPage < pages.length && currentPage != 0)
                page = currentPage - 1;
            pageChange(page);
        }

        function pageChange(page) {
            currentPage = page;
            $(".list-item").removeClass("active");
            $("#page_" + page).addClass("active");
            $(".page-data").html("");
            page = pages[page];
            printRows(page);
        }

        function printRows(arr) {
            arr.forEach(element => {
                $(".page-data").append("<tr><td>" + element.id + "</td><td>" + element.employee_name + "</td><td>" + element.employee_salary + "</td><td>" + element.employee_age + "</td></tr>");

            });
        }

        function paginate(arr, size) {
            return arr.reduce((acc, val, i) => {
                let idx = Math.floor(i / size)
                let page = acc[idx] || (acc[idx] = [])
                page.push(val)
                return acc
            }, [])
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Good one! helped me a lot creating custom component with vue js 1.